# rails g scaffold articles isn't executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to generate a scaffold in an existing project but when I run the command `rails g scaffold articles title:string date:string content:text image:string` nothing happens...

```
$ rails g scaffold articles title:string date:string content:text image:string
```

I can't ever generate a controller???
`rails g controller articles` do nothing....

If I try in a new project it works what could be the problem please ?

Comment: which version of rails

Comment: Hi  I have 4.2.5 ( I have installed rails 5 but not using it on this project)

Comment: are you able to see something like rails --help

Comment: I just found ! I had to stop spring.... First time it happens !! but it's ok now

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `stop spring` and everything is back to normal  !